# 0 rows inserted - How can I fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I an trying to INSERT multiple rows into an SQL, Oracle table though SQL Developer v3.0.04

the Database was set-up by Uni so I don't know what version it is.

after looking on-line I have come up with the code below but it will not INSERT any data.  I have tested the insert with just one row and that is OK.  What am I missing?

```
Insert all 
  Into Patient Values
    ('101', '1 house', Null, 'Kingston', 'Surrey', 'KT1 1XX', '10/jan/1980', 'm', 01452987456)
  Into Patient Values
    ('102', '2 egg rd', 'vail', 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 1LL', '05/dec/1985', 'm', 01452987456)
  Into Patient Values
    ('103', '6 station rd', Null, 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 2XX', '15/may/1990', 'f', 01452987456)

Select * from Patient;
```

Comment: I had never seen 'insert all'... Do you need for it to be a single instruction insert?

Comment: To get version `select v$version from dual;`

Comment: What error if any are you receiving?

Comment: @AleojBrz the `all` keyword is part of Oracle's multi table insert syntax. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2121682 Useful for inserting into multiple tables in the same cluster so you can get the data close to each other. (Cluster being http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#sthref77)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

INSERT ALL has two different uses.  One is to insert different sub-sets of selected columns into a table.  The other is to direct rows into different according to certain criteria.  In both cases the data comes from a SELECT clause rather than from VALUES.  [See the examples in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2125362).

Normally, you would simply write multiple `INSERT` statements potentially in a single PL/SQL block.  Something like

```
begin
  Insert Into Patient Values
    ('101', '1 house', Null, 'Kingston', 'Surrey', 'KT1 1XX', '10/jan/1980', 'm', 01452987456);
  Insert Into Patient Values
    ('102', '2 egg rd', 'vail', 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 1LL', '05/dec/1985', 'm', 01452987456);
  Insert Into Patient Values
    ('103', '6 station rd', Null, 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 2XX', '15/may/1990', 'f', 01452987456);
end;
/
```

If you really want to do this in a single SQL statement, you can do an `INSERT ... SELECT` but that's generally going to be more complex than using three separate statements.

```
insert into patient
  select *
    from (select '101' id, '1 house' addr, null col1, 'Kingston' city, ...
            from dual
          union all
          select '102', '2 egg rd', 'vail', 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 1LL', '05/dec/1985', 'm', 01452987456
            from dual
          union all
          select '103', '6 station rd', Null, 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 2XX', '15/may/1990', 'f', 01452987456
            from dual)
```

I would also caution you to use proper data types and to specify the column names in your `INSERT` statement.  I'm guessing, for example, that the first column of `Patient` table is some sort of `PatientID` that is defined as a `NUMBER`.  If so, you'd really want to insert a number rather than a character string.  Similarly, the seventh column with values like '15/may/1990' is probably defined as a `DATE` in the table.  If so, your `INSERT` should insert a `DATE` not a character string by either explicitly calling `TO_DATE` with a particular format mask or by using the ANSI date format, i.e. `date '1980-01-10'`.  And if you want the last column to retain the leading 0, you'll need to ensure that the column in the database is defined as a `VARCHAR2` and that you insert a character string rather than a number.

Comment: Thank you Justin!  all of you assumptions are right,  although I didn't mean to quote the ID at the start.

Both solutions worked well but I like the response from the second solution as it tells you the number of rows inserted opposed to the first solution that just says "anonymous block completed". I'm guessing that if I state the column names that that may change.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. It is possible to use `insert all` to insert multiple rows as you are attempting.  Not that I would recommend doing so over Justin's suggested solutions.

The [syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2121682) for multi-table insert indicates that a subquery is always required. However, you don't have to use any of the results of the subquery:

```
SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t (c1 number, c2 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert all into t (c1, c2) values (1, 'one')
  2      into t (c1, c2) values (2, 'two')
  3  select * from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from t;

        C1 C2
---------- ----------
         1 one
         2 two
```

The two `into ... values(...)` will cause two rows to be inserted per row in the the subquery:

```
SQL> insert all into t (c1, c2) values (1, 'one')
  2      into t (c1, c2) values (2, 'two')
  3  select * from dual
  4  connect by level <= 10;

20 rows created.
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  unfortunately the first post was more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this query [ Select * from Patient; ] with
Select * from dual;

dual is a virtual table which is not existing in our schema but it can be existed as a part of Oracle perspective in RAM not in our storage

Insert all
Into Patient Values
('101', '1 house', Null, 'Kingston', 'Surrey', 'KT1 1XX', '10/jan/1980', 'm', 01452987456)
Into Patient Values
('102', '2 egg rd', 'vail', 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 1LL', '05/dec/1985', 'm', 01452987456)
Into Patient Values
('103', '6 station rd', Null, 'guildford', 'Surrey', 'GU1 2XX', '15/may/1990', 'f', 01452987456)

Select * from dual;